# How can I draw the rectangle including the surfPoints object on the image?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, feature-detection, surf

I have a grayscale image I want to extract the regions of interest using detectSURFFeatures(). Using this function I get a surfPoints object.
by displaying this object on the image I get circles as regions of interest.
For my case I want the rectangular areas encompassing these circles.
To be more clear i have a image 1:

[image: initial image]

I want to extract Region of Interest (ROI) using : detectSURFFeatures(), we obtain the image

[image: image after detection]

if you can see we have circular region, and for my case i want the rectangular ROI that contains the circular region :

[image: results desired]

Comment: `rectangle` might do the trick, for you.

Comment: My problem is i don't have the radius of the circles all i have is the surfpoints informations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the radius is fully determined by the `points.Scale` parameter.

```
% Detection of the SURF features:
I = imread('cameraman.tif');
points = detectSURFFeatures(I);
imshow(I); hold on;

% Select and plot the 10 strongest features 
p = points.selectStrongest(10)
plot(p);


% Here we add the bounding box around the circle.
c = 6; % Correction factor for the radius
for ii = 1:10
    x = p.Location(ii,1); % x coordinate of the circle's center
    y = p.Location(ii,2); % y coordinate of the circle's center
    r = p.Scale(ii);      % Scale parameter
    rectangle('Position',[x-r*c y-r*c 2*r*c 2*r*c],'EdgeColor','r')
end
```

And we obtain the following result:

[image]

In this example the correction factor for the radius is `6`. I guess that this value correspond to half of the default Scale propertie's value of a `SURFPoints` object (which is `12.0`). But since there is no information about that in the documentation, I can be wrong. And be carreful, the scale *parameter* of each ROI is not the same thing as the scale *propertie* of a `SURFPoints` object.

Comment: Thank you sir @obchardon your answer work for me thank you a lot.I have one question why the value is 6 as you montioned no information about it in the documentation. and what about the orientation of our rectangular because we can change the orientation of the obtained rectangular using the informations obtained by the surfPoints

Comment: Since there is no information in the doc I cannot be sure that my explanation is correct. Try to create a random `surfPoints` object with a different value for the `scale` propertie and check if my explanation still works. For the rotation you can simply use a rotation matrix to rotate the rectangle's coordinates and draw the result with `plot`.

Comment: Thank you sir a lot for your time and help